# Como carregar aquivo HTML usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tenho um arquivo `HTML` o qual quero fazer a contagem de todas as tags `a` existentes. Já consegui desenvolver o script que faz essa contagem usando o Local Storage.

O meu objetivo é:

- Ao ser carregada a página `index.html`, o script vá no outro arquivo `html` que eu quero e faça a contagem das tags.
- Que essa contagem seja exibida em uma `td` no `index.html`

Aqui segue o script que faz a contagem e o Local Storage:

```js
var linkCount = document.body.querySelectorAll('a').length,
hrefs = document.body.querySelectorAll('a[href]');

localStorage.setItem("links", linkCount);

document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("links");
```

O script acima está executando apenas localmente, ou seja, onde é feita a dele.

Imagino que exista uma forma de fazer a chamada do arquivo que eu quero na execução desse script, mas não consigo achar.

Espero ter sido o mais claro possível e posso complementar caso fique confuso. Obrigado desde já!

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é você fazer uma chamada nesse "*outro arquivo HTML*" via AJAX e posteriormente tratar como você já faz, mas com pequenas alterações. Veja esse exemplo:

**index.html:**

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Resposta na td abaixo:</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="alvo"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
            if (ajax.status === 200) {

                // https://stackoverflow.com/a/20583524/5988245
                let ajaxDocument = (
                    document.implementation
                    .createHTMLDocument().documentElement
                );
                ajaxDocument.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;

                /* Seu tratamento:
                 * var linkCount = document.body.querySelectorAll('a').length,
                 * hrefs = document.body.querySelectorAll('a[href]');
                 **************************************************************/

                 // Como fica:
                let linkCount = ajaxDocument.querySelectorAll('a').length,
                hrefs = ajaxDocument.querySelectorAll('a[href]');

                // Popular na td:
                document.getElementById('alvo')
                .innerText = 'linkCount: '+linkCount;

                // debug:
                console.log(linkCount);
                console.log(hrefs);

            } else {
                // debug:
                console.log(ajax);
                alert('Erro na requisição.');
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.open('get', 'outroarquivo.html');
    ajax.send();
</script>
```

Nesse exemplo, utilizei `outroarquivo.html` com 6 links:

```
<!-- ... -->
<body>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
</body>
<!-- ... -->
```

E esse foi o resultado:

[image: Print do resultado]

---